# What's a plus sign before variable assignment in recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

In a Bitbake recipe file (`.bb`), I have the following assignments:

```
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/some_lib"
+FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/var/spool/foo/bar"
```

The second line has a plus sign before the variable name being assigned.

Tried searching for it in the Bitbake Manual, Google and even ChatGPT, but it seems to be understanding it as the append operator (`+=`) instead of the use I have here. I also thought of it being a typo, but Bitbake process the recipe, so I think it actually has a meaningful use.

What is the purpose of it?

Does it have a special name so one can actually search for it in documentation?

Comment: Never seen that before, maybe bitbake interprets it as a new variable starting with a "+". Where did you find this ? It processes the recipe, but does it work and ship the files ?

Comment: @PierreOlivier It's a private recipe from before I joined the company, so I don't know the history of it. Yes, it works and the files are on final image (If that's what you mean). In other words: everything (seems to) works just fine. I followed your hint of the variable name. Indeed, `bitbake -e |grep` shows the variable created with the `+` in the front. So it looks like it is just a case of a typo that went unnoticed for years? Quite disappointing. `:(`